# GRAILS: send parameter to renderEditor.template

Tags: grails

I need to send a parameter to the file renderEditor.template (After of installing of "grails install-templates"), but I have no idea how. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you expound upon what you are trying to do a little? renderEditor.template is just used to translate form fields into calling the private methods in that file when rendering HTML forms. How or what are you trying to do that would require passing a parameter into that. Just trying to understand the goal...

Comment: I know, but I need to send a parameter by the call in _form.gsp "renderEditor(p)" ,for example, renderEditor(p, "myString") to  manipulate in renderEditor.template    .Sorry the english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding variables available to `renderEditor.template` are fixed in [DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-scaffolding/blob/master/src/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/scaffolding/DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator.groovy)

```
    def binding = [pluginManager: pluginManager,
                   property: property,
                   domainClass: domainClass,
                   cp: cp,
                   domainInstance:getPropertyName(domainClass)]
```

`domainClass` being the `GrailsDomainClass`, `property` being the `GrailsDomainClassProperty` that was passed to the `renderEditor(p)` call in the scaffolding template, and `cp` being the corresponding `ConstrainedProperty`.  You may be able to extract what you need from one of those.

Comment: Alright, How to know  by these objects which template the renderEditor is rendering? I have two diferent situations in two diferent templates that i have to process by the diferent ways.  Sorry the english

Comment: @PhillipParente I don't think you can unfortunately.  I can see that it wouldn't be too hard to modify `DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator` to make it possible to pass in arbitrary parameters to your `renderEditor.template` but I can't see any way to achieve it without such code changes.

Comment: Ok, is the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For other people who got here via Google with the same problem (as I did)

I've managed to do so in similar way as Ian Roberts suggested, but you don't need to create new implementation for Template Generator. All you need is to create a proxy implementation for **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClassProperty**

inside of _form.gsp I did just created new property with added data:

```
p = new HgfGrailsDomainClassProperty(p, prefix, domainClass)
if (display) { %>
<hgf:ifAllowedOnField action="show" field="${p.name}">
<hgf:ifReasonToShow reasonElement="${p.name}" bean="\${${propertyName}}">
<div class="fieldcontain \${hasErrors(bean: ${propertyName}, field: '${prefix}${p.name}', 'error')} ${required ? 'required' : ''} ${(cp?.metaConstraints?.hiddenField)?'hiddenProperty':''}">
    <label for="${prefix}${p.name}">
        <g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${prefix}${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" />
        <% if (required) { %><span class="required-indicator">*</span><% } %>
    </label>
    ${renderEditor(p)}
...
```

Implementation can look something like this:

```
package sk.hoppo.hgf;

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClassProperty

public class HgfGrailsDomainClassProperty implements GrailsDomainClassProperty {

private final String domainSuffix = "Instance";
private GrailsDomainClassProperty property;
String prefix;
String domainInstance;

public HgfGrailsDomainClassProperty(GrailsDomainClassProperty property, String prefix, GrailsDomainClass parentDomainClass) {
    super();
    this.property = property;
    this.prefix = prefix;
    domainInstance = getPropertyName(parentDomainClass);
}

private String getPropertyName(GrailsDomainClass domainClass) {
    return "${domainClass.propertyName}${domainSuffix}";
}

@Override
public int getFetchMode() {
    return property.getFetchMode();
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return property.getName();
}
...
```

Inside the renderEditor.template you just access the send data:

```
sb << '<hgf:securedField'
sb << ' name="' << property.prefix << property.name  << '"'
sb << ' field="' << property.prefix << property.name  << '"'
```

BTW. with this I've made composition (embedding) to work with my custom renderEditor correctly